# Qt qml error"Unable to assign [undefined] to QDeclarativeGeoMapType* "

Tags: qt, google-maps, qml

I am developing an application, where I am in need of adding the Google map into myapplication. I am using Qt with QML. I generated the API key, but after run the code, it only loads a blank gray screen. Can someone recommend some ideas on how to debug this. It is difficult with only this error message:

> "Unable to assign [undefined] to QDeclarativeGeoMapType*"

```
Plugin {
           id: googleMaps
           name: "googlemaps" // "mapboxgl", "esri", ...
           // specify plugin parameters if necessary
            PluginParameter {
                name:"googlemaps.maps.apikey"
                value:"AIzaSyAl4e5Qaf5mYadK_BH3G7721yEcgt_Xcu0"
            }
       }
Map {
        id: myMap
        anchors.fill: parent
       plugin: googleMaps
//        plugin: hereMaps
        activeMapType: supportedMapTypes[2]
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(19.997454, 73.789803)
        zoomLevel: 8

        GeocodeModel {
            id: geocodeModel
            plugin: myMap.plugin
            autoUpdate: false
            query: {
                geocodeModel.query = "India"
                geocodeModel.update()
                //console.debug()
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is the equivalent of assigning a null-pointer. I think it is on this line: `activeMapType: supportedMapTypes[2]`. Try checking if that `supportedMapTypes` is actually filled etc

Comment: The google map plugin doesn't come by default. Have you installed it?

Comment: I have tested it using the plugin downloaded since https://github.com/vladest/googlemaps and it works correctly

Comment: No I didn't installed any plugin.How to install it can you help? @eyllanesc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, you have not installed the [`googlemaps`](https://github.com/vladest/googlemaps) plugin so you must follow the following steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/vladest/googlemaps.git
cd googlemaps/
mkdir build
cd build/
qmake ../
make
sudo make install
```